# Send order confirmation mail to contact instead of account owner in Shopware B2B Suite

Tags: shopware6

We have an ERP integration which has data sovereignty. All changes are made through the ERP.
The problem now is that orders go to the mail of the main account and not to that of the contact who placed the order.

The ERP only has a logic of customer accounts with contacts, but no email address for the main contact. So we had to create fake email addresses. Also, the ERP has no authorization logic. Meaning there is no admin or anything like that. So we can't just take the first user for example, because this could also be deactivated.

So I do know, that this how B2B Suite is designed, but it doesn't fit our needs.
What's the best way now to send the email to the account of the ordering contact, or at least a copy?

Answer (score 1):

The B2B-Suite currently always assigns the order to the customer account. However, the information about which contact placed the order is stored in the b2b tables.

I would suggest that to follow this guide [Add data to mails](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/mail/add-data-to-mails).

With the order-data, you could load the B2B-order-context and the Contact-Information and replace the recipients with the correct email.

Useful services would be:

```
Shopware\B2B\Order\FrameworkOrderContextRepository::fetchOneOrderContextByReferencedOrderId()
Shopware\B2B\StoreFrontAuthentication\Framework\StoreFrontAuthenticationRepository::fetchAuthenticationById()
Shopware\B2B\StoreFrontAuthentication\Framework\IdentityChainIdentityLoader::fetchIdentityByAuthentication()
```